# How to returned a typed single result from ASP.NET Core API using IResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Background, I want to develop a new API using ASP.NET Core 7 and using controllers and I want to use best practices to return typed results to simplify the documentation for example.

If I want to return a typed result from an API, I can do:

```
[HttpGet()]  
public ActionResult<List<Products>> GetAllProducts()
{
    var beers = repository.GetAllProducts();

    return beers;
}
```

but, my question is if I want to return and use one of the derived classes from **IResult** instead (for consistency reasons), then the following below will not work, because Results requires two return types.:

```
[HttpGet()]  
public Results<Products> GetAllProducts()
{
    var beers = repository.GetAllProducts();

    return beers;
}
```

Sure, I could do a hack like this:

```
[HttpGet()]  
public Results<Products,BadRequest> GetAllProducts()
{
    var beers = repository.GetAllProducts();

    return beers;
}
```

But that sounds a bit silly.

What is the recommended type to result if I want to use IResult and I only want to return one type? Or is ActionResult<List> the only option?

I feel that to get a bit more clean code and be modern that I want to stick with IResult based types and not mix with IActionResult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need

```
        [HttpGet()]
        public IResult GetAllProducts()
        {
            var beers = repository.GetAllProducts();

            return Results.Ok(beers);
        }
```

Comment: Not really, that would of course work but I like the typed result type approach , like you get with  Results<Products,BadRequest>", to get a better documentation and without having to add additional attributes.

I am looking for the correct/best way to do this in .NET 7. I know there are many options here (ActionResult<T>) but at the same time, what is the correct way? IResult seems to be the way forward for pure APIs.

Comment: @JoeMarkov I may misunderstood. Could you show a sample of the result you want to get?

Comment: I guess there is no solution today, I wanted to return IResult, but ony one Typed result, like "public Results<Products> GetAllProducts()" , but there is no Results type with only one generic parameter. I will use ActionResult<T> for now

Answer (score 1):

From ASP.NET Core 7, you can use [typed HttpResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-7.0#httpresults-type).

So you can specify in the action method signature the expected HTTP result :

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResults;

public class FoosController
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    // When the action has one result type
    // specify directly the result type
    public Ok<List<Foo>> Get()
    {
        List<Foo> foos = ...
        return TypedResult.Ok(foos);
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    // When the action has several result types
    // use the generic Results
    public Results<Ok<Foo>, NotFound, BadRequest> Get(int id)
    {
        Foo? foo = ...
        if(foo == null)
            return TypedResult.NotFound();
        return TypedResult.Ok(foo);
    }
}
```

---

Actually, the action metadatas aren't correctly inferread from typed HttpResult Swashbuckle don't the generate the expected OpenApi schema. See this GitHub issue for more detail :
[TypedResults metadata are not inferred for API Controllers](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44988)

While waiting for a resolution, I do a operation filter to generate OpenApi response from HttpResults type and I wrapped it in a NuGet package :
[Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter)

You can add the package :

```bash
dotnet add package Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter
```

So you can register the filter :

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    ...
    options.OperationFilter<Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter.HttpResultsOperationFilter>();
});
```

If you prefer, you can just copy/paste the filter file from the package repository :
[HttpResultsOperationFilter.cs](https://github.com/vernou/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter/blob/main/src/Vernou.Swashbuckle.HttpResultsAdapter/HttpResultsOperationFilter.cs)